# Trying to pass numpy array mode value to df column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have created a small program to find the mean, median and mode values for two particular columns of a df. I used np.mean and np.median to find the mean and median values but for the mode i created a numpy array from the df and calculated the mode. I print them to the console and the values seem fine, however i would like to get the mode value from the numpy array to appear in my df that has four columns for 'STUDENT' 'score' 'mean' and 'median'. I am wondering if there is a way to get the mode value and attach to the end of the df to have a fifth column titled 'mode'. My code is below to take a look. I would like to not use libraries like scipy for this also so as to not use sparse if there is another way around it.

```
def mean_median():
    df = pd.read_csv('Surveys.csv')

    dfm= df.groupby("STUDENT")[["SCORE"]].agg([np.mean, np.median]).reset_index()

    print(dfm)


    arr = dfm.to_numpy()

    print('\nNumpy Array\n----------\n', arr)
    vals,counts = np.unique(arr, return_counts=True)
    index = np.argmax(counts)
    return vals[index]
```

Here is an example of my output if it helps makes things clearer to understand

```
    STUDENT      SCORE       
                mean      median
0      2443.0  93.210145   94.0
1      2445.0  94.652113   95.0
2      2447.0  93.919775   95.0
3      2451.0  95.203571   95.0
4      2832.0  94.544304   95.0
..        ...        ...    ...
276   27323.0  95.585106   96.0
277   27324.0  94.562105   95.0
278   27325.0  96.986348   98.0
279   27326.0  96.809524   97.0
280   27334.0  96.102564   97.0

[281 rows x 3 columns]

Numpy Array
----------
 [[ 2443.            93.21014493    94.        ]
 [ 2445.            94.65211268    95.        ]
 [ 2447.            93.91977481    95.        ]
 [ 2451.            95.20357143    95.        ]
 [ 2832.            94.5443038     95.        ]
 [ 2838.            94.97988265    95.        ]
 [ 2839.            93.88054608    94.        ]
 [ 2841.            93.90789474    94.        ]
 [ 2980.            94.14044944    95.        ]
 [ 3220.            94.44219067    95.        ]
 [ 3221.            93.80825959    94.        ]
 [ 3222.            93.88416076    94.        ]
 [ 3229.            98.42857143   100.        ]
 [ 3231.            92.11363636    93.        ]
 [ 3236.            94.3677686     95.        ]
 [ 3238.            93.84027778    94.        ]
 [ 3332.            93.12958963    94.        ]
 [ 3333.            92.83663366    93.5       ]
```

sample input data from a few rows to try and recreate

```
 STUDENT        SCORE
 
  25718         97            
  25719         97             
  26990         95           
  23809         92          
  24032         90            
  22723         87            
  24688         92           
  25714         89            
  25718         78            
  23078         90            
  25713         90
  24032         87
  26990         77
  26990         89
```

Comment: please provide a sample reproducible input data so that we understand what you are referring to.

Comment: I updated the post with the current output if that helps

Comment: Please add few rows of an input as well.

Comment: Sorry i am not following you? Which input data?

Comment: Please check [ask]. Its expected that when asking a question you provide a minimum reproducable input. In this case, `df` from `'Surveys.csv'`. That would help someone to replicate your situation and allow them to quickly solve your question.

Comment: Check my answer, I have had to create a dummy dataset but it should solve your problem. Let me know incase any issues :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, sorry for the misunderstanding. I will update with some sample data. By the way now i am getting ValueError: no results after running my program with your updated code. What might be the issue?

Comment: cant say until you put some data man.

Comment: Added some input data if it helps at all.

Comment: So you are taking mean, median , mode of the zipcode?

Comment: No, sorry i am taking mean, median and mode scores of student groups. For example student group 24098 has a median score of 89 and so on.

Comment: I have added another case, where if a student doesnt have a single mode, then the value returned is average of the multiple modes . this will allow you to not get an error.

Comment: Do check my solution and if it helped you, mark it as correct. It would encourage me to help you with your future questions.

Comment: Perfect, the lambda function runs without an error and helps get the desired output!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227032/discussion-between-coderman-and-akshay-sehgal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.Series.mode` for calculating mode. Also, for mean and median you can simply use strings to reference the functions.

```
#Dummy dataframe
d = {'STUDENT': [25718, 25718, 25718, 25718, 25718, 22723, 22723, 22723, 22723, 22723, 25713, 25713, 25713], 
     'SCORE': [97, 97, 95, 92, 90, 87, 92, 89, 78, 92, 90, 87, 87]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
out = df.groupby("STUDENT")["SCORE"].agg(['mean','median',pd.Series.mode]).reset_index()
print(out)
```

```
   STUDENT  mean  median  mode
0    22723  87.6      89    92
1    25713  88.0      87    87
2    25718  94.2      95    97
```

**This will give results if there exists a mode (at least one repeated value for each student). If there is no mode, it will throw an error.**

More details [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html).

---

If you are not sure whether each student has a defined mode or not, you can simply take an average of the mode values returned by `pd.Series.mode`. If it returns a mode, its average is the same. If it returns multiple modes, you return average of those.

```
d = {'STUDENT': [25718, 25718, 25718, 25718, 25718, 22723, 22723, 22723, 22723, 22723, 25713, 25713, 25713], 
     'SCORE': [97, 97, 95, 92, 90, 87, 92, 89, 78, 92, 90, 87, 88]}

mode = lambda x: pd.Series.mean(pd.Series.mode(x))

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
out = df.groupby("STUDENT")["SCORE"].agg(['mean','median', mode]).reset_index()
out.columns = ['STUDENT','mean','median','mode']
print(out)
```

```
   STUDENT       mean  median       mode
0    22723  87.600000      89  92.000000
1    25713  88.333333      88  88.333333
2    25718  94.200000      95  97.000000
```